# Sudo Mv Renaming Mess Up

Tags: unix, terminal, macbook-pro

Okay, first things first Mac OS Mavericks MacBook Pro. Now, I used sudo mv to rename my Desktop and user folder. NOT the folder actually called user, but my user within that (it was neomartinson). Regardless, I have switched the names back but I don't seem to have rwx capabilities. I checked with ls -l and I do have those capabilities for both folders. The reason it doesn't seem like that is that every time I try and save something it says no permission and I can't open new webpages.

Please don't inform me of the obvious by stating I shouldn't have done.

Comment: So can you give it rwx permissions again?

Comment: I have tried that. Ls -l now states I have full rwx permissions on both folders. It looks like: rwxr--r--

Comment: Ownership is ok? Can you post the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: Read above comment. What do you mean ownership?

Comment: Holy bejesus I fixed it! Thank you for your comments all, sorry!

Comment: So how did you fix it? Please post it as an answer below to help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a relatively simple solution, that I totally overlooked. The folders are all name sensitive. My theory is every folder/app under your cd ~/ area uses that name in it's coding somewhere. By renaming just that in terminal, you confuse the other programs because they look for your normal folder. The only way to change it is to do it apples way, which will change the dependencies too.

Comment: Maybe you should just delete the question of not actually a real problem.

Comment: Ouch holy community. Sorry if I don't know how to delete a question. Is that evident from my ONE point?